# MI UI Permission Manager result

Tags: android

I'm creating an app to send SMS. While sending the SMS, I'm displaying a progress dialog which is dismissed based on the result of SMS_SENT broadcast receiver.

Everything is working fine but the issue is with devices running MI UI. Since MI UI has it's own permission manager built in. If the user denies the permission for SMS, the progress dialog is never dismissed. Is there any way to know that the permission has been denied for devices running MI UI (API < 23)?

Answer (score -2):

use below code it will surely solve your problem

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission
                    .SEND_SMS);
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;

            }
    }
```

Comment: But I want to check the permission for devices running API less than 23??

Comment: use directly then int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission
                    .SEND_SMS);
            if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;

            }

Comment: it will always return true.

Comment: if someone not having permission then it will return false